# multi level login system in codeigniter, not working

Tags: codeigniter

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

My login system is OK. It's working..
I have three 'user_type'
1.admin
2.supar admin
3.user

I need , if login into admin & supar admin or user. its  redirect three different view.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to corresponding dashboard based on user type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Check the following steps and you may change it.

**Signin controller**

```
public function signin()
{
   //Assume this is your session details after successful login check
    $data = array
    (
        'member_user_id' => $row['id'],
        'member_username' => $username,
        'member_usertype' => $row['user_type'],
        'member_logged_in' => TRUE
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

   switch($row['user_type']){
    case 'user':
     redirect('user/dashboard');
    break;
    case 'admin':
     redirect('admin/dashboard');
    break;
    case 'super_admin':
     redirect('super_admin/dashboard');
    break;
   }
}
```

And, you can validate the session in required controller method based on user type. so that user can not view admin or super admin pages vice versa.

**User Details Controller**

```
public function user_details(){

  if ($this->CI->session->userdata('member_usertype') != 'user'){
     redirect('login');
  }

  //implementation code here
}
```

**Admin Details Controller**

```
public function admin_details(){

  if ($this->CI->session->userdata('member_usertype') != 'admin'){
     redirect('login');
  }

  //implementation code here
}
```

**Super Admin Details**

```
public function super_admin_details(){

  if ($this->CI->session->userdata('member_usertype') != 'super_admin'){
     redirect('login');
  }

  //implementation code here
}
```